# Nested for loops on data.table with complex sub-setting to populate empty data.table

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have a data.table (dt) that looks like this -

```
unigene  s.start   s.end
1:  70333442   25564   25601
2:  47901818  151379  151340
3:  22804559  237716  237685
4:  51650325  370382  370338
5:  45665472  691509  691553
6:  67902793  885586  885616
7: 107540914  909650  909617
8:  22777344 1234774 1234752
9: 103835796 1421236 1421263
10:  46208443 1595024 1595059
```

I have this code with nested for loops, which for some reason is popoulating the data.table much slower than when it was a data.frame. How can I make it run faster? Which parts of my code are slowing it down?

```
paretoPoints <- data.table(
l = integer(),
c = integer(),
u = integer())

for (m in 1:nrow(dt)) {
    for (n in 1:nrow(dt)) {
        if (m > n) {
            a <- as.numeric(dt[m, 4])
            b <- as.numeric(dt[n, 3])
            c <- as.numeric(abs(length(unique(dt[n:m]$gene))))

            s <- head(which(dt2$s == as.numeric(b)), 1)
            e <- tail(which(dt2$e == as.numeric(a)), 1)

            dt3 <- dt2[s:e]
            u <- length(unique(dt3$gene))

            paretoPoints = rbindlist(list(paretoPoints, list(a-b, c, u)))
  }
 }
}
```

I have tried using combn(1:nrow(dt), 2, fun), but it didn't work.

Comment: This is not how you do things in R generally and `data.table` specifically. Calling `[.data.table` in the loop is what slows you down, and yes that will be significantly slower than `[.data.frame`. Add a reproducible example with ideally a smaller subset of your code, and it'll be easier for someone to point you to the right direction.

Comment: @eddi Have added an example dataset.

Comment: Your code does not run with your sample data.